# Linkedin rest API, How to search the organisation by name for @mention list?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to find the LinkedIn rest API which will allow me to search the organization by name, can someone help me with it?

I got one API that has that capabilities, but that API keeps saying I don't have enough permission to access: GET-search /companySearch API

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/companySearch? 
q=search&query=LinkedIn%20Corporation' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}'
```

Response:

{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access: GET-search /companySearch","status":403}

Does anyone know which permission I need to access this API